# Forgot passphrase of an encrypted disk

Tags: security, disk-management

I did the encrypted disk option upon setup and have forgotten my passphrase. I wrote down the backup code it gave me, but don't know where to use it.

Also, how do I turn off this encryption? It's more worry than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

At this point if you don't have really done any kind of customization, you might just reinstall the OS without the encryption.

Comment: yup ... without passcode you are screwed